# ajax success event not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

In my MVC aplciation i am using ajax post to reload some part of the view. I am using following jquery to post

```
          $.post(
                 '<%= Url.Action("SearchResult", "Search") %>',
                 { content: 'GetCallDetails' },
                 function (result) 
                     { success(result); }
             );

             function success(result) {
                alert("Test message.");
                 $("#player").html(result);
              }
```

From contoller I am returning like this

```
  return PartialView("SearchResutPlayer", searchModel);
```

Its not partially reloading the ascx and i cant even see that test mesasage? Any idea?

Comment: Is the controller action called?

Comment: there was sopme problem with ascx file.Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post('/SearchResult/Search',{ content: 'GetCallDetails' },
          function (result) 
             {
               success(result);
              }
       );
```

Try This.

Check whether your action in controller is called by puting a debug point